# macOS 11: Get system information (GPU, resolution) programmatically (in C)

Tags: macos, resolution, gpu, system-information, system-profiler

I need to access data about GPU and screen resolution in C, not using `system_profiler`, because it takes too long(.3s-.5s `system_profiler SPDisplaysDataType`), and needs greping and cutting, which is not that fast either.

Caching would be answer, but very short-sighted as someone can use different monitors etc.

Unfortunately system_profiler is closed source.

EDIT: I used CGDisplayPixelsWide and CGDisplayPixelsHigh to get resolution. During compilation i had to compile with `-framework Cocoa -framework IOKit`. Only minus that it gets system resolution rather than screen resolution. So function looks like this.

```
static char *get_resolution()
{
        int screen_width = CGDisplayPixelsWide(CGMainDisplayID());
        int screen_height = CGDisplayPixelsHigh(CGMainDisplayID());
        ...
}
```

Comment: This might need an edit to be on topic here. Code level questions would get migrated to Stack Overflow, but interactive scripts (python with objective C bindings specifically) and grep plus system calls can also be powerful and performant. We don’t have enough detail to go on for more than the two helpful answers provided already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[displayplacer](https://github.com/jakehilborn/displayplacer) allows to read and write display settings and is open source. I'm not sure about GPU details though.

The API used seems to be defined in `IOKit/graphics/IOGraphicsLib.h`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not certain of specific APIs, but looking at the source code of an open source application that works with display resolutions or GPUs may be beneficial. Two examples I can think of are [RDM](https://github.com/avibrazil/RDM) and [gSwitch](https://github.com/CodySchrank/gSwitch) (RDM hasn't been updated for a while but there are up-to-date forks available).